# What visa should freelancer without education apply if employer wants him to temporary work in USA?

Tags: usa, visa, freelance

I have started studying programming 4 years ago and started freelancing 1 year and a half ago and my current employer wants to invite me and my girlfriend to go to USA to work there temporarily (3-9 month not sure yet). 
What kind of visa should I apply for and what documents will I need? Does he need to send me an invitation? Do I need to prove that we are in a relation with my girlfriend?

Comment: Your employer should handle the visa process. Do you mean the employer actually invited your girlfriend as another employee, or just said that she could go with you? Do be aware that scammers target job seekers so if this is a new employer (client?) this may not be a legitimate offer.

Comment: @user16259 he said she could go with me. Concerning the scammers - we have worked with him 1.5 years on freelance platform and he just needs me there to work for 3-6 month, so that the building process would be quicker.

Answer (score 1):

You actually can not apply for any work visa in the US. Your employer can apply for a visa for you (probably H1B). The only visa you could apply for is a tourist visa that explicitly prohibits you from working.

Comment: To clarify the terminology, for most employment-based visas, the employer _petitions_ USCIS. After the petition is approved, the beneficiary (worker) applies for a visa if and when one is needed. Canadian nonimmigrants don’t need a visa in most cases, including H-1B, and the petition can also include an application for change of status if the beneficiary is already in the US, in which case a visa is only needed during the next trip out of the US. TN status for Canadians and Mexicans does not require a petition.

Comment: Given 1.5 years working for the employer, it may be possible to petition for an L1 "person with specialized knowledge" visa.